# What foods can I eat to keep my energy up in an office job in the afternoon?

Tags: energy, sugar

About 2-3 hours after eating lunch I crash at work. My hands shake, I can't concentrate and I generally believe this has to do with low blood sugar. I've never been diagnosed with diabetes. My mom has it, so it does run in my family.

I feel like, in many ways this would be the best time for me to exercise, but instead I'm trapped at a desk until 6. The best remedy I've found are the low-carb slim fast shakes. I've tried nuts, and granola bars, all unsuccessfully. Without eating another meal, nothing else has worked.

I wondered if anyone had any tips regarding natural sources for managing mid-afternoon blood sugar levels and keeping my energy levels up at work (without getting up and moving).

Comment: @Svha If you really believe that your low blood sugar is the problem, I would rather see that confirmed first rather than ask a question based on speculation.

Comment: What types of food are you eating for lunch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snack on food with a low Glycemic index (most fruits and vegetables, legumes/pulses, whole grains, nuts, fructose) instead.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycemic_Index):

> A lower glycemic index suggests slower rates of digestion and
>   absorption of the foods' carbohydrates and may also indicate greater
>   extraction from the liver and periphery of the products of
>   carbohydrate digestion. A lower glycemic response usually equates to a
>   lower insulin demand but not always, and ***may improve long-term blood
>   glucose control*** and blood lipids.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely go to a doctor and get it checked if there's any history in the family at all and it's as extreme as you say.

For general energy, something like almonds, beef jerky, and protein shakes are good.

Answer (score 1):

Many people are used to lots of sugar input to the bloodstream, via carb-heavy meals and snacks throughout the day. This can lead to a spike-and-crash cycle that leaves you tired, especially in mid-afternoon. Changing to a low carbohydrate diet and skipping breakfast can help condition your cells to maintain steady energy levels without glucose input from digestive sources. For me, intense exercise after a half day or longer fast also helped.